# Amdgpu drivers and Ubuntu 16.04.04 LTS

Tags: amd-graphics, lts, ubuntu-drivers, amdgpu

So I have tried installing amdgpu from and site on a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04.04 LTS to get my rx Vega 64 working and it is not working as expected. When I install and reboot my login goes into an infinite loop of asking for my password which I supply then asks again.

Tried a few online workarounds but the only thing that works to get back into the system is to uninstall the ampgpu drivers.

So my Ubuntu is running with no hdmi sound or graphics for the time being any work around for Rx Vega 64 support?

Comment: Did you get any further?

Answer (score 1):

It's a long shot but this might be due to your display manager. I had a problem similar to that you describe when I was using `sddm` and running the amdgpu drivers for my Athlon Kaveri APU (graphics reported as Radeon R7).

My solution was to

```
sudo apt purge sddm*
```

Followed by

```
sudo apt install lightdm
```

My system still bugs out when switching between users (logout) but I can login as normal from the initial user login prompt.

You'll need to switch to a console (Ctrl+Alt+F1) or boot in recovery mode in order to run the commands.

Comment: I think display managedir is actually a likely suspect for login loop. You can also switch to console and restart the display manager with sudo systemctl restart lightdm or sudo systemctl restart sddm but this would have you lose any work that is in the system. This isn't complete as he still needs hdmi sound which has nothing to do with display manager though which is something I am not an expert on by any means.

Comment: Thanks guys so I found out amdgpu is only supported in 4.15 kernel so need to upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 from some folk over on Reddit.

Comment: @GarrithGraham, I don't quite understand your comment - do you mean it doesn't work for your graphics card? I've been using it since Kubuntu 16.10 I think and I'm only on kernel 4.13. In the [wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AMDGPU-Driver) it says "Support for AMDGPU begins with Ubuntu 16.04 ".

Comment: That's right but everyone says only kernel 4.15 works it may be for my card tho not the amdgpu drivers.